# Are monoids useful in optimization?

Tags: optimization, compilers, category-theory

Many common operations are [monoids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid). Haskell has leveraged this observation to make many higher-order functions more generic (`Foldable` being one example).

There is one obvious way in which using monoids can be used to improve performance: the programmers is asserting the operation's associativity, and so operations can be parallelized.

I'm curious if there are any other ways a compiler could optimize the code, knowing that we're dealing with a monoid.

Comment: Coincidentally, the author of the HLearn library has a [series of posts](http://izbicki.me/blog/gausian-distributions-are-monoids) on this now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiler can optimize exponentiation with monoids. Let $\oplus$ be a binary operator calculateable in constant time such that $\oplus$ and $a_1, a_2, ... \in A$ form a monoid. Then the operation

$$\bigoplus_{[1..n]} a_k = \underbrace{a_k \oplus a_k \oplus \dots \oplus a_k}_{\text{$n$ times}}$$

which usually takes $\cal O(n)$ time can be evaluated with the square and multiply algorithm in only $\cal O(\log n)$ time if the compiler knows that $\oplus$ obeys the monoid laws.

Comment: Nice observation.  Maybe you should specify that you are assuming that $a_k \oplus a_k$ can be computed in $O(1)$ time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the constant folding/constant propagation step, whenever you come up with the identity of the monoid, you can just ignore it if it's multiplying other non-constant expressions.

Comment: I was thinking about this - do you know if it's actually faster?

Comment: It could make a difference inside a loop, for example.